# Passing php variable from one form to another page with hidden value

Tags: php, forms, variables, hidden

After passing a php variable(Tno) from one page to another page using button with hidden value,  with that variable(Tno) tried to retrieve the data from the database, but I am not able to retrieve with that variable i.e. Tno. I had attached form1.php and retrieve.php.

**form1.php**

```
   <?php
   session_start();
   ?>

   <?php
   if( isset ($_SESSION["Email"])) {
   $con=mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password");
   // Check connection
   if (!$con)
   {
   //echo "i am not ale to connect.<br>";
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   else{
   //echo " i am able to connect.<br>";
   }

    mysql_select_db("maintable", $con);

    $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Email']);


   $sql1="select * from customer where Email=('$Email')";
   $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
   $var1 = $row['Identity'];
    }
   //echo" Email of the customer = $Email.<br>";
   //echo "identity of the customer = $var1.<br>";

  $sql2= "SELECT * FROM  `suptest` WHERE Tno LIKE '$var1%'";
  $result2=mysql_query($sql2); ?>
  <table border=0 width=50%>
  <tr> 
  <th>Ticket Ref. No.</th> <th>Subject</th><th>Status</th></tr>
  <?php
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){ 
  $ticketno= $row['Tno'];
   ?>
  <form  action="retrieve.php" method="post">

  <tr><td><?php echo $row['Tno']; ?><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Tno']; ?  >" name="Tno" /></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['sub']; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
 <td><input type="Submit" value="Update" /></td></tr>
 </form>
 <?php
 } ?>
 </table>
 <?php
 mysql_close($con);
  }
  ?>

    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <html><head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","admin","password");
    //echo "Check connection";
    if (!$con)
    {
    //echo "I am not ale to connect.<br>";
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else{
    //echo "I am able to connect.<br>";
    }
    mysql_select_db("maintable", $con);
   $Tno = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Tno']);

   //echo "my tno is $Tno.<br>";
   $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['Email']);
   echo $Email;
   $sql = "select * from `active1active1` where Tno = ('$Tno')";
   if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   $result=mysql_query($sql);
   echo $result;
   echo mysql_num_rows($result);
   echo "entering while loop";
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
   { 
    echo "entered while loop";
    echo $row['Tno'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['Email'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['pdesc'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['Activity'] . "<br />";
     }
     ?>

     </body></html>
```

Comment: Did you check print_r($_POST);

Comment: i dont see a hidden input anywhere in your posted script.

Comment: See the color difference up over there and fix the same.

Answer (score 1):

im going to take a stab here:

this line

```
  <tr><td><?php echo $row['Tno']; ?><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['Tno']; ?  >" name="Tno" /></td>
```

should be this?

```
<tr><td><?php echo $row['Tno']; ?><input type="hidden" name='Tno' value="<?php echo $row['Tno']; ?  >" name="Tno" /></td>
```

note i added type=hidden and a name for the input

try:

```
 $sql = "select * from `active1active1` where Tno = '" . $Tno . "'";
```

Comment: hidden values are passed to another page, with using that using value iam not able to reteive data from database with select query in reteive.php

Comment: what does print_r($_POST) show you on the retrieve.php page?

Comment: it's correctly showing the value, but not able to reteive data from database. Select statement which I have written in retreive.php page is correct or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 value="<?php echo $row['Tno']; ?  >
```

There should not be any space after ?
change to **?>**

```
<form  action="retreive.php" method="post">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Tno']; ?>" name="Tno" />
            </td>  
            <td>
                <input type="Submit" value="Update" />
            </td>
          </tr>
         </form>
```

---

retrie` 
try this simply:

```
   $Tno = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Tno']);

   echo  $sql = "select * from `active1active1` where Tno = '$Tno'";


   $result=mysql_query($sql);

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
     print_r($row);
   }
```

---

Comment: i tried the value is correct only iam not able to retreive from database

Comment: echo  $sql = "select * from `active1active1` where Tno = '$Tno'"; die();
this will print query in your browser.try to run this query in your phpMyadmin to verify query

Comment: in phpMyadmin the results are perfect

Comment: i have editied my answer please try with this, i have removed if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
   }

Comment: after removing also that retreiving data is not done.

Comment: have you done same as i have edited in answer like:

$result=mysql_query($sql);

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
   {
     print_r($row);
   }

Comment: yes i tried what you have written, not able to retreive

Comment: what do you mean by not able to.   is print_r($row) blank?  do you get an error?

Comment: remove everything from your page and add just code to fetch $Tno and display records as i mentioned above. There seems to be some syntax error at some other place in your page.

Comment: echo mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: i removed other lines when echo mysql_num_rows($result); is giving 0

Comment: it means there is no record in your database corresponding to your current value of $Tn. Try with other value of $Tn manually which is present in your database so that you can confirm